# Darboux theorem from Rudin PMA

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

He consider cases when $f'(a)<f'(b)$ or $f'(a)>f'(b)$. But what about $f'(a)=f'(b)$?

What did you think about this dear users?

Comment: If $ f'(a) = f'(b)$, you might ask if there exists $ x \in (a, b) $ such that $ f'(x) = f'(a) = f'(b) $. The answer is: not necessarily.  For example, take $ f(x) = \sin(x), a=0, b= 2\pi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f'(a) = f'(b)$, then the condition

$$f'(a) < \lambda < f'(b)$$ cannot hold.

Comment: So what? Theorem is false in case?

Comment: @RaheemNajib No, the theorem is vacuously true in that case.

Comment: Maybe there are some another points namely $c,d$ such that $f'(c)<\lambda<f'(d)$?

Comment: @RaheemNajib Sure, that's possible (although not necessarily true). But that's not relevant: If the assumptions are false, then the theorem still holds; it just doesn't tell you anything. Also, please allow more than three minutes to elapse before adding a follow-up ping....

Comment: Can i ask you also one question? Why if assumptions are false then the theorem is true?

Comment: @RaheemNajib https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth

Comment: Thank a lot for your help!